# output records in the form of html table from moodle database , custom block development

Tags: moodle

Please check this code for the custom block to be placed in the dashboard. We want to display an HTML table for the records. But it does not add up to the custom block, rather it appears on the top page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVUUM.png)

class block_scorecard extends block_base {

```
function init() {
    $this->title = get_string('pluginname', 'block_scorecard');
}
function get_content()  {
    global $DB;

    if ($this->content  !== NULL) {
        return $this->content;
    }

    $content = '';

    $courses = $DB->get_records('scorm_scoes_track', ['element' => 'cmi.core.total_time']);
   $table=new html_table();
$table->head=array('No of attempts','Time modified','status');
    foreach ($courses as $course) {
   
        $attempt=$course->attempt;
    $timemodified=userdate($course->timemodified, get_string('strftimerecentfull'));
        $status=$course->value;
    
       $table->data[]=array($attempt, $timemodified, $status);
    }
    echo html_writer::table($table);
$this->content = new stdClass;
$this->content->text = $content;       
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo html_writer::table($table);
```

Should be

```
$content .= html_writer::table($table);
```

Comment: And for displaying data in this form like below:
Course name: 
Time created: